# when opening a jQuery UI dialog page scrolls up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

you can see it here: http://mrgsp.md:8080/awesome/lookupdemo *(make your browser window smaller, scroll down and click on a button near a textbox)*

is there a way to make it not scroll up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

since you are using anchor tags you need to suppress the default behavior of the element. by calling [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$("a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //do stuff
}
```

Looking at your current javascript, something like this should work for you:

```
   $("#lpo" + o).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (lckPerson != null) return;
        lckPerson = true;
        $.get('/awesome/PersonLookup', {
            prop: o,
            paging: 'true'
        }, function (d) {
            $("#lp" + o).html(d).dialog('open');
            lckPerson = null;
        });
    });
```

Comment: i think this is too complicant. just use javascript:void(0) and thats all... that is the reason of scrolling, and this is alsoo very unnecesarry to create an event to each button for the click, only change the href.

Comment: javascript:void(0) would work as well however I do not know the extent of the application.  It is possible the href might be used for something if javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the links are refered to the "#" which is the page top.
If you change this to `href="javascript:void(0)"` this will not link to anything and will not scroll up.

Comment: the page is not reloaded.. it just goes to the top due to the `#` in the links